# How to plot intermediate layers when predict image using Keras and TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to plot intermediate convolutional layer filters to understand how my CNN work when i predict image using an already trained model.

I am using Keras and TensorFlow.

I load the model in this way:

```
model = load_model()
```

and then i use predict to get a numpy array as output.

```
score = model.predict(input_data,100,verbose=1)
```

Is it possible to plot the intermediate convolutional layer and filter?

Comment: Sure, you can checkpoint your model after every layer, and then fit and load it into the image array to get the required visualizations.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Could you provide me an example of code? i am not so expert using Keras.

Comment: You could follow the instructions from [this](https://github.com/gabrielpierobon/cnnshapes/blob/master/README.md)